# online Derech Hashem translation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, english, ramchal

I am looking for an online english translation of Derech Hashem (Way of God) by the Ramchal.

Comment: Sefaria has it http://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem,_Introduction.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all in Hebrew ...I know they have some system that allows for translation requests, but I'm not familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

http://torah.org/learning/ramchal/archives.html

Very loose translation into English. But it will give you the idea of the text. A better idea would be to purchase the Aryeh Kaplan translation. It's fantastic and like with everything he did, the footnotes are priceless.

[http://www.amazon.com/Way-God-Classics-Library-English/dp/087306769X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087306769X)

Comment: None of these links given above actually give you a complete english version of Derech Hashem. They are either partial summaries or only small portions translated are available from these links.